# ターミナルを開くとエラー env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

ターミナルを新規で開くと下記文が表示されてしまいます。
削除するためにはどのような対応をすれば良いのでしょう？

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `~/.bashrc` や `~/.bash_profile` の中身を確認して質問文にテキストのままはりつけてみてください。

Comment: 似たような状況の記事がこれらですが、その記事のように詳細な情報を追記した方が良いでしょう。[How to reset Bash on Mac OSX, .bash_profile corrupted and bash no longer works](https://superuser.com/q/498312), [env: bash: No such file or directory on Mac #6985](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/6985), [env: bash: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52039080/9014308)